# "mvn test" runs testng instead of Junit

Tags: maven, junit, cucumber

When I run "mvn test" no tests are run and in the report I see that testng was somehow invoked - how is this possible ?

Ultimately mvn does not run any test.

Could someone help ? I dont have any testng library in the code. Maybe pom is incorrect or something is missing  ?
Ultimately mvn does not run any test.

Could someone help ? I dont have any testng library in the code. Maybe pom is incorrect or something is missing  ?

````
After running "mvn test" it invokes test ng:

Running cucumber.Options.TestRunner

Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf" 


My pom looks like this:

pom.xml



  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <properties>

</properties>
  </properties>
  
  
 

  <dependencies>
  
  
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->

    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.9.1</version>
</dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>6.9.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
</dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->

    
    
    
  </dependencies>

</project>

When I run mvn test command I get 



[INFO] Scanning for projects...

[INFO]

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Building APIframwork 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO]

[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ APIframwork ---

[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.

[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Test\eclipse-workspace\APIframwork\src\main\resources

[INFO]

[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ APIframwork ---

[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

[INFO]

[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ APIframwork ---

[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.

[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Test\eclipse-workspace\APIframwork\src\test\resources

[INFO]

[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ APIframwork ---

[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

[INFO]

[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ APIframwork ---

[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\Test\eclipse-workspace\APIframwork\target\surefire-reports



-------------------------------------------------------

 T E S T S

-------------------------------------------------------

Running cucumber.Options.TestRunner

Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@7006c658

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.506 sec



Results :



Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0



[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time: 11.381 s

[INFO] Finished at: 2021-10-13T15:12:56+02:00

[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/180M

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------```
````

Comment: What if you're doing not `mvn test` but `mvn clean test`?

Comment: How does your directory/file structure look like? In which directory are your tests? What also seems strange to me is that your pom.xml specifies surefire 2.22.2 but your console output displays surefire 2.12.4. Is the output up-to-date and in the correct folder of the correct project?